# JPARepository - sometimes create duplicate records

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have the following entity class.

```
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper=false)
@ToString(callSuper=true)
@Entity
@Table(name = "storeitem")
public class StoreItem extends SellableStoreItem {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  private UUID id;

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @ToString.Exclude
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "store_id")
  private Store store;

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @ToString.Exclude
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "storeitemcategory_id", nullable = true)
  private StoreItemCategory storeItemCategory;

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "storeItem")
  private List<StoreItemTranslation> storeItemTranslationList = new ArrayList<>();

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "storeItem",
      cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
      orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<StoreItemOptionCollectionSelection> storeItemOptionCollectionSelections = new ArrayList<>();

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @Column(name = "uid")
  private UUID uid = UUID.randomUUID();

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @CreationTimestamp
  @Column(name = "createddate", nullable = false)
  private LocalDateTime createdDate;

  @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude
  @Column(name = "iscurrent", nullable = false)
  private boolean isCurrent = true;
```

And in my service layer, I do the following.

```
  private StoreItemResponse setStoreItemCreate(StoreItemDTO storeItemDTO, Store store, StoreItemCategory storeItemCategory) {

    StoreItem storeItem = new StoreItem(storeItemDTO, store, storeItemCategory);
    if(storeItemDTO.getUid() != null){
      storeItem.setUid(storeItemDTO.getUid());
    }
    storeItem = storeItemRepository.save(storeItem);

    // Create Translations for store Item
    for (TranslationDTO translationDTO : storeItemDTO.getTranslationDTOs()) {
      StoreItemTranslation translation = new StoreItemTranslation(translationDTO, storeItem);
      storeItemTranslationRepository.save(translation);
    }


    return new StoreItemResponse(storeItem.getId(), DtoResponseStatus.OK);
  }
```

However, when testing the code, I notice that there are times (not often but some cases) I see duplicate records (with different id) are being saved to database. And the duplicates are saved 2ms apart so I suspect  storeItem = storeItemRepository.save(storeItem); created the duplicate records.

Why would this happen?

Comment: If you're debugging and you hit Evaluate Expression and then go to next Breakpoint then that statement will be executed twice, If not, there might be some other problem.

Comment: I tried but the problem is that this duplicate doesn't always happen so it is very hard to catch the debug trace.

Comment: You save the storeItem, assign it to a translation and save the translation.Since those two are mapped via one to many relation, it should be enough to only save the translation and the storeItem is saved automatically by spring. I would guess your duplicates are caused by this double save.